# How can i set two different colours for two different listviews in kendoui,

Tags: css, kendo-ui

I am using .css file for the styles. In my view page i am having two list views and i want two different colours for two of the list views. How can i do that in kendo ui

Regards,

Sri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix your CSS definition by listview `id`, discriminating between one and the other.

Given the HTML for the ListViews:

```
<div id="ListView1"></div>
<div id="ListView2"></div>
```

and a JavaScript:

```
$("#ListView1").kendoListView({
    dataSource: sharedDataSource,
    selectable: true,
    template: "<li>${title} ${year}</li>"
});
$("#ListView2").kendoListView({
    dataSource: sharedDataSource,
    selectable: true,
    template: "<li>${title} ${year}</li>"
});
```

The CSS definition would be something like:

```
#ListView1 .k-state-selected {
    background: red;
}
#ListView2 .k-state-selected {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: I am having two listviews with their id as Listview1 and Listview2 then in css                                                   #listview1 .k-listview .k-state-selected                            { background-color:red }                                    #listview2 .k-listview .k-state-selected                            { background-color:blue }                                          is that i need to do

Comment: See the added example... Basically remove the `-color` in the definition. You need to set it as `background` even that you only define the `color` since there is also an `background-image` definition that you need to remove.